# My Raspberry Pi 3 B won't work with the touchscreen

Tags: pi-3, touchscreen, kali

So i've got a KeDei 3.5" touch screen Version 6.3 and i installed an image of Kali with the driver that's given of KeDei's website (http://kedei.net/raspberry/raspberry.html) but it hasn't been working, the display doesn't display anything, it just turns on when the Rasp does, i have been searching all over for the answer to my problem but i haven't found it yet, i hope i'll be able to find it here.

Comment: read the info on the KeDei webpage .... do you have a supported RPi?

Comment: The fact that it "turns on" is a very good sign.  That is a test of pin assignment and some of the circuitry.  I would expect that to mean it is a software problem.  I trust someone here will be able to help.

Comment: jsotola : i do have a supported RPi, i checked and rechecked

Comment: SDsolar : if it's only a software problem, then i'm reassured, i was worrying i had to buy another one when i'm running low on money

Comment: @Bones, look again ... what three devices does Kali support? .... RPi B is not one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.- check in the vendor page your device is supported by RPI3.
2.- check in the vendor page if your device supports the OS your RPI3 is running.
3.- check in the vendor page if your device need some special drivers for touch related to each OS.
4.- some screen devices are usable with raspbian, other OS's does not seem to work or at least not properly.

i bought like 3 chinnesse screens ( two of these with touch ), but at this point i haven't be able to make it work, other times they should be connected to make the touch work but the cables does not come within the package, and also you have to use the correct voltage to make all the screen work as expected.

Comment: thanks, i double checked everything and apparently it doesn't work with kali on a RPi 3 b